# Example of $\{X_1, X_2,\dots,X_N\}$ is an unordered basis but $(X_1,\dots,X_N)$ is not a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Where the definition of an unordered basis is:
 a subset $X$ of the abelian group $G$, $X$ is an unordered basis of $G$ if it is independent and spans $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that for $G=\Bbb Z$, letting $N=2$, $X_1=1$, $X_2=1$ we have that  $\{X_1,X_2\}=\{1,1\}=\{1\}$ is an unordered basis of $G$, but $(X_1,X_2)=(1,1)$ is not an ordered basis of $G$ (it is not independent).

Comment: But is {X1,X2} independent? They're not linearly independent